# Are there any games which are made using flash (as3) and javascript together?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I was thinking about making a game using as3 and javascript together but i have yet to see any. i know that the two languages can work together but i can't find games that use them both.

If anybody could tell me about any games like this or if it is somewhat impossible to do so could you tell me why?

Comment: I would like to recommend you: http://pushbuttonengine.com/ I'm not sure it provides you a javascript bridge, but you can do pretty much anything with this framework.

Comment: Various social games may use JS to put notifications on page header. Other than that, there is little need to add extra moving parts. You can connect two (maybe different) game instances on one page with JS and use it somehow though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I am an expert from what I understand they cannot use the same canvas and it is almost certain that communication between the two languages will be slow. So any game is almost certainty going be made in one or the other as it would be far easier and better overall to just pick one language. Now if you need JS to do the networking while flash does the rendering and game logic I know a friend of mine was looking into doing something like that. But I would classify that as a Flash game that just happens to need some JS on the webpage to run right.

Maybe you should clarify what you mean by "making a game using as3 and javascript together"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the comments so far and I think it's worth thinking about whether or not you can accomplish what you're trying to do with either one or the other without using both, that should probably be your course of action.

As for original request for an example, this is (at least so far) by far the coolest example I've seen so far. It's a Pong game where one half of the board is Flash and the other half is HTML/Javascript. It's worth noting this example makes use of the `<canvas>` tag and therefore can only be accomplished using HTML5, but it's still pretty sweet.

http://labs.codecomputerlove.com/FlashVsHtml5/

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with @Jonathon. Say you want to have a set of html controls that drives an option set for a flash game... maybe those controls are integral to gameplay.

Well, great. ExternalInterface is robust and powerful, but why use it in a situation like this?

Flash is robust and powerful by itself, and doesn't necessarily need any help to do much of anything. I will definitely run some javascript to plant the swf on the page, assist in networking, or set some default variables, but beyond that, flash doesn't have much to *gain* from reliance on other tech (save for server communication). Certainly not speed. I think you don't find many "true" dual tech apps like this for precisely this reason.

A bigger question, that is more apropos: do you *need* flash to accomplish your goals? I love working with flash, but if native browser tech can accomplish the same goal, then its an unnecessary layer. And if it can't, well, then Flash it is.

For the time-being, as far as games are concerned, frameworks like tweenlite, pushbutton, flint etc... still give flash a convincing lead.

Cheers